# Plotting a graph in android

Tags: java, android, graph

I'm very new in android development. i need to plot a dynamic graph in where the value had to be stored in sqlite database. I'm using jjoe64 graphview library to plot it... the problem now is on how to insert the string as a value to the graph. I've tried and search for the solution but still couldn't find for a perfect solution....

**The code is like this :-**

```
import com.jjoe64.graphview.BarGraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.GraphViewData;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphViewSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.LineGraphView;

import dev.starmobile.database.MarkAdapter;
import dev.starmobile.database.MarkOpenHelper;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    public class GraphActivity extends Activity {
    MarkAdapter adapter;
    MarkOpenHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph);
        adapter = new MarkAdapter(this);

        double sem = Double.parseDouble(helper.SEMESTER);
        double mark = Double.parseDouble(helper.MARK);

        GraphViewSeries markValue = new GraphViewSeries(
                new GraphViewData[] {sem,mark });

        GraphView myGraphView = new LineGraphView(this // context
                , "Performance" // heading
        );

        myGraphView.addSeries(markValue); // data

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layout.addView(myGraphView);

    }
```

**declaration in database**

```
// public static final String SEMESTER = "STUD_SEM";
// public static final String MARK = "STUD_MARK";
```

Comment: I suggest top look at the AWork project [https://jwork.org/dmelt/awork/](https://jwork.org/dmelt/awork/) for Android. This application looks like a code editor, but you can program any chart/graph using a simplified Java syntax (BeanShell). You can make plots dynamic too. But I know little about the library you are using.